# How to remove duplicated react? (Invalid hook call)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

When using libraries (I tried `styledcomponents` and `react-router`), an error appears in React applications:

> Warning: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
>
> You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
>
> You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
>
> You might have more than one copy of React in the same app See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

After clicking on the link and reading the documentation, I decided that for some reason I have several versions of React or something like that, since after doing this point:

```
// Add this to node_modules/react-dom/index.js file
window.React1 = require('react');

//Add this to your component file
require('react-dom');
window.React2 = require('react');
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);

//If it prints false then you might have two Reacts and need to figure out why that happened. 
//This issue(https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991)
//includes some common reasons encountered by the community.
```

Here is the code:

```
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import './index.css';
import AboutPage from './pages/aboutpage';
import BlogPage from './pages/blogPage';

require('react-dom');            //checked for duplication as written in the 
window.React2 = require('react'); //documentation (see above)
console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <header>
          <a href = '/'>Home</a>
          <a href = '/posts'>Posts</a>
          <a href = '/about'>About</a>
        </header>
      </div>
     </Router>
  );
}
export default App;
```

The error appears right after I wrap in `<Router></Router>`

node_modules/react-dom/index.js (path from documentation)

```
'use strict';
function checkDCE() {
  if (
    typeof __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__ === 'undefined' ||
    typeof __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.checkDCE !== 'function'
  ) {
    return;
  }
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production') {
    throw new Error('^_^');
  }
  try {
    __REACT_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__.checkDCE(checkDCE);
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  checkDCE();
  module.exports = require('./cjs/react-dom.production.min.js');
} else {
  module.exports = require('./cjs/react-dom.development.js');
}

window.React1 = require('react');     //did as written in the documentation
```

I got `false`. After clicking on the link with the solution from the community (https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991),
I honestly did not understand any of the solutions.

Maybe someone met this problem and can help me?
PLEASE :(

Comment: Please share the component that triggers the error

Comment: sorry, added the code to the post